# I'm stuck on file upload (allways not accpting uploading)

Tags: file-upload, primefaces

I'm stuck ... I followed several tutorial but I do not know what's my problem ... I need to uplod  files in the Repertoir C: \ PDF
but I do not get to do

this is my

```
<h:form enctype="multipart/form-data">

<p:fileUpload

mode="advanced"

fileUploadListener="#{composantbean.upload}"

allowTypes="/(\.|\/)(gif|jpe?g|png)$/"  sizeLimit="100000" description="Select Images"

auto="true"/>

</h:form>
```

this is my methode on bean

```
@ManagedBean(name="composantbean")
@SessionScoped
public class Composantbeam {
private String destination="C:\\PDF\\";

public void upload(FileUploadEvent event) { 
FacesMessage msg = new FacesMessage("Success! ", event.getFile().getFileName() + " is uploaded."); 
FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(null, msg);
// Do what you want with the file       
try {
copyFile(event.getFile().getFileName(), event.getFile().getInputstream());
} catch (IOException e) {
e.printStackTrace();
}
} 
public void copyFile(String fileName, InputStream in) {
try {
// write the inputStream to a FileOutputStream
OutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(new File(destination + fileName));
int read = 0;
byte[] bytes = new byte[1024];
while ((read = in.read(bytes)) != -1) {
out.write(bytes, 0, read);
}
in.close();
out.flush();
out.close();
System.out.println("New file created!");
} catch (IOException e) {
System.out.println(e.getMessage());
}
}
}
```

this is my error message it allaws shown when a upload a file

```
    C:\PDF\C:\Documents and Settings\Admin\Bureau\login.png (Syntaxe du nom de fichier, de répertoire ou de volume incorrecte)

C: \ PDF \ C: \ Documents and Settings \ Admin \ Desktop \ login.png (syntax file name, directory or incorrect volume)
```

Comment: When I add this <init-param>
      <param-name>uploadDirectory</param-name>
      <param-value>D:\PDF</param-value>
      </init-param>

Comment: it works fine ..why ??

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that event.getFile().getFileName() is returning filename with complete path

so I change My methode Like this

```
File result = new File(destination+ ***FilenameUtils.getName***(event.getFile().getFileName()));
```

Commons IO offers FilenameUtils#getName() for the exact purpose.
think you all :)